# Automate scripts

Tags: oracle, scripting, plsql

I have bunch of SQL statements and I want to put them in a script and run them together and produce an EXCEL (*.xls) file; how can I do that in toad?

Example of script

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
             WHEN dvdn.ACDCALLS = (dvdn.ABNCALLS + dvdn.ABNCALLS1) 
             THEN dvdn.ABNCALLS    
             ELSE dvdn.ACDCALLS + dvdn.ABNCALLS - dvdn.ABNCALLS1 
           END) AS InboundCalls 
  from ccrdba.CMS_DVDN dvdn , ccrdba.VDN_DIM dim
 where DIM.DW_VDN_ID = DVDN.DW_VDN_ID (+)
   And DETAIL_GROUP like 'HD%'
   and vdn_name not like '%ASM%'
   And DIM.AGENT_GROUP <>'Smart Specialist'
   And row_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2012-SEP-01', 'YYYY-MON-DD')AND TO_DATE('2012-SEP-30', 'YYYY-MON-DD')
```

Second Statement

```
select count(*)
  from xx_new.xx_online_registrations@appsread.prd.com oreg
 where oreg.client_party_id = 141043767
   and oreg.cti_id IS NOT NULL
   and oreg.created_by = 'IVR-INTERACTIONS'
   and TRUNC(CREATION_DATE) between '01-SEP-2012' and '30-SEP-2012'
   and status = 'POSTED'
   and last_updated_by = 'IVR-INTERACTIONS'
```

Like above there are about 10 SQL statements. How do I combine them together in ORACLE?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this in TOAD. I had a similar problem and ended up writing a Python script that would execute the queries and use Excel's COM API to put the data in a report.

Comment: so what - if any - is the relationship between these queries?  And if there is none, precisely how do you want to lay out or organise the disparate results?

Answer (score 0):

You can try "union all",

```
        select col1 from table1
        union all
        select col1 from table2
        union all
        ...
```

Comment: But that will give me aggregated data by each SQL i get some number that is valuse of one column in excel. For example  Total Inbound Calls gets data from 1st qry, then Successful Registrations Completed in IVR gets data from second qry.....